# Issue with array in Objective-C, want to reuse array but unable to delete previous values

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode, uicollectionview

I have an issue with an array I am using inside of the following function

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This function gets called with UICollectionView. The code that is giving me problems is below:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCollectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSInteger *numEmptyCells = (int*)([self getNumberFirstDayOfMonth:[self getNameOfFirstMonthDay:datePickerDateString]]);


    if (!tempMutableArray)
    {
        tempMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [tempMutableArray removeAllObjects];
    tempMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



    for (int i = 0; i < [self getNumberFirstDayOfMonth:[self getNameOfFirstMonthDay:datePickerDateString]]; i++)
    {
        [tempMutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
        //[tempMutableArray addObject:@"empty"];
    }

    [tempMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:monthDatesObjectsArray];

    if (cell != nil)
    {
        if ([tempMutableArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]])
        //if ([tempMutableArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"empty"]])
        {
            //[cell updateCollectionCell:nil cellImage:nil];
            [cell setHidden:true];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell updateCollectionCell:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (indexPath.row - (int)numEmptyCells + 1)] cellImage:nil];
        }

    }

    return cell;

    //return nil;
}
```

What I have is that I am calling another function and all the objects in it get added to the array below called `tempMutableArray` which first gets added a number of values that are supposed to be detected below by the if statement

> if ([tempMutableArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
>   indexPath.row]])

So first those values are added to `tempMutableArray`, and then another array is added to `tempMutableArray` called `monthDatesObjectsArray`. What I have is that when the cells are first populated with values the function works like I want it to, but the second time the cells are populated with values the values that are added from the for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self getNumberFirstDayOfMonth:[self getNameOfFirstMonthDay:datePickerDateString]]; i++)
    {
        [tempMutableArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
        //[tempMutableArray addObject:@"empty"];
    }
```

have random numbers, which then mess up the rest of the cells, because if those values have values equal to other values in the cells then those cells are disabled by `[cell setHidden:true]`. How can I make sure every single time the cells are populated with values I don't get random values? Please see the link I provide for some screenshots. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Screenshot images: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzaP1abbReAhVzhCeEY2eFZibFE&usp=sharing

Comment: Really work on understanding object and their lifetimes. there is no point in removing all objects from the `NSMutableArray` only on the next line creating a new `NSMutableArray` for the same variable.

Comment: Can't access screenshots without permission - also you're `init`ing `tempMutableArray` twice. Also note that this method is called _every_ time a cell needs to be displayed so doing object creation/manipulation inside of it is not ideal if the results can be reused

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried allocating the `tempMutableArray` outside of `cellForItemAtIndexPath` but the results I want only happen the first time collectionview loads the cells. The second time and on the for-loop does not work, rather when I check what the loop is adding to the array are random numbers before the cells start displaying 1, 2, 3, in order. So if the other cells have same values they get disabled by `[cell setHidden:true]`. Why would the for-loop only work the first time? Is there a way to properly clear the array? I'm not sure why it's not working. I fixed link above.